# ASP.NET MVC5 custom AuthorizeAttribute not being invoked properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**tl;dr:** My custom attribute overriding AuthorizeAttribute's AuthorizeCore method is not being properly invoked -  leading to unrestricted access.

**Long Story:** I have a ASP.NET MVC5 application with four roles (Administrator, Scheduler, Trainer and Student). Until now I used the built in

```cs
[Authorize("Administrator")]
```

attribute on classes and methods of my controller (View and API) to perform Windows Authentication against an Active Directory which works as expected.

Now I wanted to change the hard-coded string names of the roles in the attributes and get the role name from the database, so that it is possible to configure the Active Directory group names via the database, while still performing the authentication directly against the Active Directory.

**Workflow:**

1. Method/Controller is allowed for the role "Administrator" only.
2. Get the "Administrator" Active Directory group from the database, t.ex. "DomainAdmins"
3. Check if the current user is a member of the Active Directory Group "DomainAdmins". If yes, grant access.

I found out, that the Authorize attribute expects a const value, so I decided to implement my custom

```cs
[DynamicAuthorize(Roles = Role.AdministratorRole)]
```

Role.AdministratorRole is a const string.

Now I saw, that for the view controller everything is working as expected. But when my API controller is being invoked (t.ex. delete user), the AuthorizeCore(...) method is **not** being invoked.

Maybe is has something to do with thread safety or how ASP.NET MVC5 works internally. I also think the code inside the AuthorizeCore(...) method doesn't matter as it isn't even invoked.

I'm grateful for any tips or advice.

**DynamicAuthorize.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.Utilities.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class DynamicAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
            }

            IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (SplitString(Users).Length > 0 && !(SplitString(Users).Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Role preparation
            List<string> allowedRolesRaw = new List<string>(SplitString(Roles));
            string allowedRolesAd = "";

            // GetRolesActiveDirectoryGroupName(...) loads role names from the database
            allowedRolesRaw.ForEach(rc => allowedRolesAd += DomainMapper.GetRolesActiveDirectoryGroupName(DomainMapper.GetRoleIdFromAttributeName(rc), true) + ", ");

            if (SplitString(Roles).Length > 0 && !(SplitString(allowedRolesAd).Any(user.IsInRole)))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
            {
                return new string[0];
            }

            var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                        let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                        where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                        select trimmed;
            return split.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Based on:

- https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs
- https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs

**UsersController.cs** (not working => not being invoked)

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Project.Models;
using Project.Utilities.Attributes;

namespace Project.Controllers.api
{
    [DynamicAuthorize(Roles = Role.AdministratorRole)]
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        // Methods in here do not have an attribute
    }
}
```

**ManagementController.cs** (appears to be working => always being invoked)

```cs
using Project.Utilities.Attributes;
using Hangfire;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using static Project.Utilities.Attributes.AntiForgeryToken;
using Project.Dtos;
using Project.Mapper;
using Project.ViewModels;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [DynamicAuthorize(Roles = Role.AdministratorRole + ", " + Role.SchedulerRole)]
    public class ManagementController : Controller
    {
        // Methods here do sometimes have an attribute if a specific action is also allowed for different roles
    }
}
```

Comment: The `AuthorizeAttribute` for web-api is in the  `System.Web.Http` namespace and is not compatible for the `AuthorizeAttribute` for mvc which is in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace (the one you are using)

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem! I added my solution to the question.

Comment: Answers do not go in the question (I have rolled back your changes)

Comment: Oh sorry, I just reedited and wondered why the changes where reverted. Shall I post to answer to a new post?

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site. Again answers (solutions) DO NOT go in the question. Again I have rolled back your changes. If you want to post your own answer, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `OnAuthorization` method on `AuthorizatioAttribute` available in `System.Web.Http` for API.

```
public virtual void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext);
```

So, **Filters for Web API are not the same as filters for MVC. The Web API filters are found in the System.Web.Http.Filters namespace**

You can get more details https://damienbod.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and linking the article. Considering this I got it to work. In the end I overrode the `IsAuthorized(...)` method. I edited my question and added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
As pointed out the problem was that MVC and HTTP controllers actually use a different implementation. Therefor my `AuthorizeCore(...)` was never called. The solution was to create another attribute (so I have `DynamicAuthorizeMvc` and `DynamicAuthorizeHttp`) implementing `AuthorizeAttribute` from `System.Web.Http` namespace. I had to override the method `protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)`. Then I use `DynamicAuthorizeMvc` for MVC controllers and `DynamicAuthorizeHttp` for API controllers. Following the working class:

**DynamicAuthorizeHttp.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace Project.Utilities.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class DynamicAuthorizeHttp : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
            }

            IPrincipal user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal;
            if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (SplitString(Users).Length > 0 && !(SplitString(Users).Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Role preparation
            List<string> allowedRolesRaw = new List<string>(SplitString(Roles));
            string allowedRolesAd = "";

            allowedRolesRaw.ForEach(rc => allowedRolesAd += DomainMapper.GetRolesActiveDirectoryGroupName(DomainMapper.GetRoleIdFromAttributeName(rc), true) + ", ");


            if (SplitString(Roles).Length > 0 && !(SplitString(allowedRolesAd).Any(user.IsInRole)))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
            {
                return new string[0];
            }

            var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                        let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                        where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                        select trimmed;
            return split.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```